# Joomla duplicate URLs for home menu items

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, menu, alias, default

I use SEO friendly URLs and it happens that my homepage is accessible through two locations:

1. http://example.com/en/
2. http://example.com/en/home/

Indeed, the title of this page is "Home" and its automatically assigned alias is "home", but then I have a duplicate content on my site.

What I would like to have is to ban the second URL (path `/en/home/`) and only use the shorter one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with .htaccess but that would be better to find the menu item that create the /home/ link and create a menu alias for that to the home page.

> Menu Item Type -> System Links -> Menu Item Alias

Comment: Thanks for the .htaccess trick. For the better solution, what I don't understand is that the menu item that create /home/ is the home page.

Comment: Home item doesn't have to put the alias in the url, you may have misconfigured something.

Comment: Good explation! Read in detail at below url
https://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-apr-2016/item/2997-avoid-duplicate-content-with-a-menu-item-alias